# Download a ruby gem fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, instagram

So I'm still pretty new to the world of Ruby, Gems, and Git.

I'm using the Instagram ruby gem, which currently has a security flaw:
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/39

In that link it contains a link to a fix. However this fix isn't part of the latest version of the gem, it was authored after the latest version bump.
How do I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require the latest copy of the code by bypassing rubygems in your gemfile.

Example:

```
gem 'instagram', :git => "https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem.git"
```

or in your case, since the code doesn't appear to have been merged into the master repository yet:

```
gem 'instagram', :git => "https://github.com/13k/instagram-ruby-gem.git"
```

You can also specify the exact commit or branch to use.

[The bundler documentation](http://gembundler.com/git.html) can guide you through the details.

This will work for you to get you going immediately. I would also, after testing that code out, comment on the [pull request](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/pull/58) to say so.